# Android: Re-Entering App Displays Different Screen

Tags: android

I am experiencing an intermittent issue.

1: I log into my application and go 2, 3 or more activities into it.
2: I press the home button.
3: I go back into the application.
4: The screen that was showing when I pressed the home button is not showing. A different screen, and not always the same screen, is being displayed.
5: I press the back button and the screen that was being displayed when I first hit the home button shows and it is in the same state as when I left it.

This can happen at any point in the application and it does not happen all the time…about 15% of the time.
If I never leave the app while I am using it, it works great.

I didn’t include any code because this issue can happen from any point within my application so I would have to publish my whole project.  The only thing that makes sense to post is my manifest file. However, posting it would show that I am not doing anything out of the ordinary.

Has anyone else had this issue? I am not using any special attributes (allowTaskReparenting, clearTaskOnLaunch or alwaysRetainTaskState)in my AndoidManifest file.

This is a hard situation to search for. If there is another similar post, I apologize. I did look and could not find another post like this.

Any help would be appreciated and if there is something you would like me to post in order to diagnose I will. I am hoping that this is just some type of config issue and can be easily resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try explaining what you are doing in each activity, and what each activity is doing when it disappears - that might give some pointers.

Comment: 1st: This issue only happens when I download load the application from my server. When I run it from eclipse, it does not ahppen.

Comment: I have a list activity that has an asynchtask in it that connects back to my server and loads some xml and parses it. That's it. It also has 3 items in the list. As per my comany's specs, I block the main thread with a dialog box until the asynch task is finished. I hit the home button, either while it is loading or after it has loaded...does not matter. Then I open the application back up and the screen before this one is being displayed, which is just another list activity with 3 items on it. If I hit the back button at this point, my list activity is displayed.

Comment: Since I run the asynchtask from the onCreate method, it does not rerun. I can pick up from that point and use my aplication as usual, but it will be confusing to our users. How do I get multiple instances of the previous activity without even calling it?

Comment: I think the problem is the result of killing the main launcher screen, which is the root activity and also the login screen (first screen in my app) Once the user is confirmed as logged in, the next sceen is instantiated and the this screen is closed. After I experience the issue and I keep hitting back, I cannot recreate the problem unless I uninstall the app and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly did not do a good job of explaining my problem. I found a site that explains my problem exactly: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373 Comment 5 is exactly the issue I am having:

"I think this same behavior is seen in launching an app after downloaded from market place, or from a 
download through the browser.

All three: eclipse, marketplace, and browser, launch our apps using this intent flag:

```
Intent { flags=0x10000000
```

and they all have the same behavior. User launches, navigates to a new activity. Hit home screen. Try 
returning to the app. The root activity is presented instead of the one they last left off at. To make matters worse, this root activity is just presented on top of the task launched previously. So hitting the back button can move all the way back to the original task.

If there's some set of flags we can specify in the manifest to prevent this behavior that would be great. Otherwise it's utterly confusing for users and I'd be surprised if there's not a way around this."

What is odd is that poeple are saying that they are having this same issue when they run from eclipse, but when I run from eclipse it works perfectly. However, when I download through a browser I get the above behavior. I didn't really answer my question, the comment fields are just too small. Prevents ranting I guess! thank you to the one person who showed some interest in my issue.